# How to get webpack-dev-server to open Brave on mac

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, brave

How can I get `webpack` to open the Brave browser when I run `webpack-dev-server` on a Mac?

For example this is how i run `webpack` and open a google chrome browser:

```
webpack-dev-server --env.mode=development --open "Google Chrome"
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac you can get `webpack` to open Brave like this:

In your `package.json`:

```
// package.json
...

"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --env.mode=development --open \"Brave Browser\"",
  },
```

Or in your webpack config:

```
devServer: {
    open: "Brave Browser",
}
```

Comment: do you know how to open brave in private mode? I've tried `arguments: ['--incognito', '--new-tab'],` but it doesn't work